# How to convert JsonNode to Date using Java 8 function

Tags: java, function

Having a common interface  with a method signature as below.

Function

for long it is implemented as below

```
Function<JsonNode, Long> getMapping ()
 {
        return JsonNode::longValue;

 }
```

How this can be implemented for JsnonNode to Date .There is no direct api to get Date from JsonNode. JsonNode has a number and it is converted to Date as blow.
 Date d = new Date(1220227200L * 1000). Would like to know how to do that conversion in the below method

```
Function<JsonNode, Date> getMapping ()
{
}
```

Comment: There isn't. What value does the `JsonNode` contain? Is it a number, a String, a boolean, a null, an object, an array? How do you convert from any of those to your `Date`? You're lacking a lot of details here.

Comment: And how do you convert a number to a `Date`? What does that number represent?

Comment: All of this should be in your question, not in comments.

Comment: There's an edit button right under your post. Please read the help center.

Answer (score 0):

Just do your calculation in a lambda expression:

```
Function<JsonNode, Date> getMapping ()
{
    return node -> new Date(node.longValue() * 1000);
}
```